# Codename One IOS signing

Tags: java, codenameone

Signing into the iOS certification wizard generates this result

REST request failed dur to internal CLI failure. See server error
log.0da699b5-3865-4d61-905b-653cc76ea2c0

After entering develoer.apple.com credentials and also clicking the check button to make sure the developer.apple.com can be reached.

[image]

Comment: We're looking into this and will get back to you.

Comment: Do you have only one device associated with your two factor authentication for Apple?
Notice that we only support one authentication device.

Comment: Yes, I have only one device

Comment: Do ever you receive the 2-Factor code on your phone?  Are you presented with the prompt to enter the 2-Factor code in the Certificate wizard?  Or does it just present this error after you press "login".  If so, how long does it take for this error to occur?  Immediately after pressing login or after some delay.

Comment: 2-factor authentication would be requested in the certification wizard, after entering the code the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks guys, have been able to log in

Comment: I have the same error now. A month ago this still worked fine. At the time I already had two devices for two factor authentication (iPhone and iPad) and that was no problem, for over a year. What changed? I tried to find a way to remove the iPad from the list of trusted devices but it seems that Apple forbids that. I want to use the Certificate Wizard but I cannot login anymore.

Comment: After a change I got an error message saying that there were pending Apple agreements/tax forms and when I filled those out on the Apple site and tried again it worked.